# git won't 'add' subdir

Tags: git

git on OSX sees a modified subdir, but won't 'add' it; how can I fix this? THANKS!
(I don't believe there are any open files in that subdir)

```
~/gitrepo/python: git status
# On branch br1
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   v0/mage-Upload (modified content)
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
~/gitrepo/python: git add v0
~/gitrepo/python: git add v0/mage-Upload    <-- I guess that was unnecessary
~/gitrepo/python: git diff
diff --git a/v0/mage-Upload b/v0/mage-Upload
--- a/v0/mage-Upload
+++ b/v0/mage-Upload
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit 7c377092f1f5cbbeecc03ebb533259c23606506e
+Subproject commit 7c377092f1f5cbbeecc03ebb533259c23606506e-dirty
~/gitrepo/python: git commit -a
# On branch br1
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   v0/mage-Upload (modified content)
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: It says `commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules` ... you are using submodules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apparently have a submodule in 'v0/mage-Upload' - you will need to handle the changes in the submodule before the changes in the 'super module'.  Do something like:

```
cd vo/mage-Upload
git status
git commit    # Careful if the submodule is not on a branch
              #   see 'git submodule' documentation
git push ...  # Specific to your submodule
```

At this point you can return the the 'super module' and commit the change to the submodule reference.

Answer (score 5):

Try to remove it from the cache and then re-add it

```
git rm --cached v0
git add v0
```

Comment: can I blow away .git/ and just re-initialize local repo?

Comment: I'm not sure how you have your project setup, but in my experience with git deleting stuff and trying to start over usually ends up in more of a headache somewhere else (unless it's all from starch).

Comment: ok, thanks for your comments. BTW: How should I 'close' / terminate this SO question?

Comment: I don't believe either of us has enough points to do that. I would just leave it open. Someone may still come along with a better answer.

Comment: I see there is a mystery .git/ in the subdir; looks like a possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186371/problem-with-modified-files-showing-up-in-git-but-not-updating?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

mage-Upload is a Git submodule. You should do the following:

```
cd vo/mage-Upload
git commit -a (or whatever you want to commit)
cd ../..
git commit -a
```

That will commit any changes in the submodule, then commit the new submodule version to the main repository.